# Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm attempting to write my first unit tests for my components and am seeing the following issues:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined.
```

How do I declare the data.iconPath in my test to get rid of the error?

This is my component:

```
import {Component, Inject, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, MatIconRegistry, MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarRef} from "@angular/material";
import {DomSanitizer} from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-snackbar',
  templateUrl: './custom-snackbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-snackbar.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class CustomSnackbarComponent {
  public readonly isSvgIcon: boolean;

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any, public _snackBarRef: MatSnackBarRef<CustomSnackbarComponent>, iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  this.isSvgIcon = data.iconPath.endsWith('.svg');
    if (this.isSvgIcon) {
      iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        data.snackBarType,
        sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(data.iconPath));
    }
  }

  close = () => {
    this._snackBarRef.dismiss();
  }

}
```

This is my test:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CustomSnackbarComponent } from './custom-snackbar.component';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBarModule, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, MatSnackBarRef } from '@angular/material';

describe('CustomSnackbarComponent', () => {
  let component: CustomSnackbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CustomSnackbarComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CustomSnackbarComponent ],
      imports: [  MatSnackBarModule, ] ,
      providers: [ { provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, useValue: {} },
                   { provide: MatSnackBarRef, useValue: {} }],
      schemas:      [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CustomSnackbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.data.iconPath = '123.svg';
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Any help on fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: change `data: any` to an actual type (such as `data:{iconPath:string}`), it may help you find where the bad data is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

here you are providing an empty config

```
{ provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, useValue: {} }
```

instead, provide the object that will not fail your code

```
{ provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, useValue: {iconPath: 'path.to.icon'} }
```